# Calculuate the differences between averages in a paired data in R

Tags: algorithm

I have a data frame as below:

```
df <- data.frame(Staff = c("Jack", "Ruth", "Michael", "Ruth", "Jack", "Jack", "Ruth", "Michael"), 
                 Client = c("Julie", "Julie", "Julie", "Julie", "Julie", "Candice", "Candice", "Candice"),
                 Assessment = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 7, 4, 1, 1), 
                 Staff_avg_by_client = c(4, 1.5, 2, 1.5, 4, 4, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `data.table` (since that's what you asked for):

We can use `by = seq(1,nrow(df))` to work on every row.

Then for each row, we can subset `df` by that row's `Staff` and `Client` using the `.SD` special symbol. So for row `1`, `.SD[,Staff]` evaluates to `"Jack"` and `.SD[,Client]` evaluates to `"Julie"`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, Diff := Staff_avg_by_client -
     df[Staff != .SD[,Staff] & Client == .SD[,Client], mean(Assessment)],
   by = seq(1,nrow(df))][]
   Month   Staff  Client Assessment Staff_avg_by_client      Diff
1:     1    Jack   Julie          1                 4.0  2.333333
2:     1    Ruth   Julie          2                 1.5 -1.833333
3:     1 Michael   Julie          2                 2.0 -0.750000
4:     1    Ruth   Julie          1                 1.5 -1.833333
5:     1    Jack   Julie          7                 4.0  2.333333
6:     1    Jack Candice          4                 4.0  3.000000
7:     1    Ruth Candice          1                 1.0 -1.500000
8:     1 Michael Candice          1                 1.0 -1.500000
```

The final `[]` is just to print the `data.table` after assigning by reference.

Comment: `Assessment` is a vector because `df` is being subset for each row.

Answer (score 2):

For every `Client` we can subtract `Staff_avg_by_client` by `mean` of `Assessment` for all other `Staff`.  Using `dplyr` this can be done as :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_by(Client) %>%
  mutate(diff = map_dbl(row_number(), 
              ~Staff_avg_by_client[.x] - mean(Assessment[Staff != Staff[.x]])))

# Month Staff   Client  Assessment Staff_avg_by_client  diff
#  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>        <dbl>               <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 Jack    Julie            1                 4    2.33
#2     1 Ruth    Julie            2                 1.5 -1.83
#3     1 Michael Julie            2                 2   -0.75
#4     1 Ruth    Julie            1                 1.5 -1.83
#5     1 Jack    Julie            7                 4    2.33
#6     1 Jack    Candice          4                 4    3   
#7     1 Ruth    Candice          1                 1   -1.5 
#8     1 Michael Candice          1                 1   -1.5
```

Comment: `row_number()` creates a row index (1, 2, 3, 4) in each group i.e for each `Client`. We use that as an index to subset corresponding values using `.x` So for first row we select `Staff[1]` ,for 2nd row `Staff[2]` and so on.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you, Ronak.